# Pass a button variable to controller codeigner 4

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I tried passing a variable on a button into the controller, but when I tried to display the value it was always null

here is my code :

```
<a class="dropdown-item edit" href="' . base_url("/purchase/edit/$row->id") . '" data-quotation="' . $row->id_quotation . '">Edit</a>
```

my ajax :

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {
    var quotation = $(this).attr('data-quotation');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: baseurl + 'purchase/senddata/' + quotation,
        data: {
            'quotation': quotation
        },
        success: function(data) {
            window.location = url;
        }.then(function() {

        })
    });
});
```

this my Controller :

```
public function edit_data($id)
{
    $id_quotation = $this->request->getVar('quotation');

    $data = [
        'title'             => 'Edit Purchase Order',
        'invoice'           => $this->purchases->getPurchase($id),
        'dataQuotation'     => $this->purchases->getQuotationById($id_quotation)
    ];
    dd($id_quotation);
    return view('purchase-order/edit-data', $data);
}
```

and this my routes :

```
$routes-\>post('purchase/senddata/(:segment)', 'Purchase::edit_data/$1');
```

on my controller there I do a var_dump but the value is always **null**

from the way I tried to do it above can someone be kind enough to tell me where I made a mistake in my code

Comment: do  `alert(baseurl + 'purchase/senddata/' + quotation)`, and check if the url is correct...

Comment: try this: base_url("/purchase/edit/".$row->id)